# Not able to load .nif module of aerospike erlang client in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, erlang, aerospike, erlang-nif

I had installed aerospike and erlang(OTP17) on the Ubuntu(12.04) machine.
Aerospike service is running fine. I had installed aerospike erlang driver.
I'm not able to connect to aerospike using erlang driver, its failing to load .nif file

I tried multiple ways along with linking the /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu to /usr/lib64 but of no help till now.

**Error information is as follows**:

```
:: Init() :: Loading aerospike NIF Module 

=ERROR REPORT==== 30-Mar-2015::23:08:55 ===
Error in process <0.40.0> with exit value: {{badmatch,{error,    {load_failed,"Failed to load NIF library: './aerospike_nif.so: undefined     symbol: RIPEMD160_Init'"}}},[{aerospike,init,0,[{file,"aerospike.erl"},    {line,70}]},{code_server,'-handle_on_load/4-fun-0-',1,[... 
=ERROR REPORT==== 30-Mar-2015::23:08:55 ===
The on_load function for module aerospike returned {{badmatch,
                                                 {error,
                                                  {load_failed,
                                                   "Failed to load NIF library: './aerospike_nif.so: undefined symbol: RIPEMD160_Init'"}}},
                                                [{aerospike,init,0,
                                                  [{file,...},{...}]},
                                                 {code_server,
                                                  '-handle_on_load/4-fun-0-',
                                                  1,
                                                  [{...}|...]}]}
** exception error: undefined function aerospike:connect/2
 in function  helloWorld:hello/0 (helloWorld.erl, line 37)
```

Answer (score 1):

I’m sure you have already seen this, but if not I found the issue discussed on the following link:

https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/erlang-nif-load-failing/159

This link describes compiling the Aerospike Erlang client, albeig on Ubuntu 14.04, and not 12.04:

http://nikola.link/?p=81

I hope this helps,

-DM

Comment: Yes, I had tried it before and it was not useful. It worked seamlessly on cent/fedora. I suspected the directory structure too but all went in vain. Anyway thanks for your quick reply.